# Will Spring boot and Dropwizard work together?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dropwizard

I have a Maven-Java project having both Spring boot and Dropwizard application packages. Can I run the Dropwizard application alone? If yes how it can be done?

consider, I have package com.project.springboot containing spring boot application and com.project.dropwizard package containing dropwizard application, help me how I can run dropwizard app alone.

**Everytime I run `java -jar target/jarfile.jar com.package.dropwizard server config.yml` It's starting spring boot application. Anyone please explain why?**

Comment: May I ask why you have both frameworks in the same project? They are almost doing the same thing (with pros and cons) The packages you say have their own pom.xml? Or they use the same one?

Comment: I just tried both framework in a project. They having same pom.xml file. I just want to know whether dropwizard can be run alone if both frameworks are there in a project

Comment: If you have both dependencies then it's up to Java to decide which one it will run first. Unless somehow you will disable one of them.

Comment: is there any way I can set the priority?

Comment: To be honest, I am not aware of that, neither could find an answer. My advice will be to separate these two dependencies to different projects